# C++ thread can't run when called std::this_thread::sleep_for

Tags: c++, stdthread

I test the code below, producer thread can't run, but remove the line `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));`,
it can work, why?

I know consumer thread existed an infinite loop

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    std::queue<int> produced_nums;
    
    std::mutex m;
    
    std::condition_variable cond_var; 
    bool done = false;
    
    bool notified = false;
    
    std::thread producer([&]() {
        pthread_setname_np("producer");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            std::cout << "producing " << i << '\n';
            produced_nums.push(i);
            notified = true;
            cond_var.notify_one();
        }
        done = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    });

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
        pthread_setname_np("consumer");
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        while (!done) {
            while (!notified) { 
//                cond_var.wait(lock);
            }
            while (!produced_nums.empty()) {
                std::cout << "consuming " << produced_nums.front() << endl;
                produced_nums.pop();
            }
                notified = false;
        }
    });
                
    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
    
    std::cout << "end" << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you exclude the `cond_var.wait(lock);` then the consumer never unlocks the mutex `m`. Without `sleep_for()` the producer may be lucky to lock it before the consumer thread can but with the `sleep_for(1s)` the chances are even more worse for the producer.

Comment: With that sleep, `consumer` is likely to lock the mutex first (not guaranteed). Since it never unlocks is, you end up with a deadlock. Without sleeping, `producer` may acquire the mutex first more probably.